# SSAS -How to select a particular attribute when we drag dimension into query editor

Tags: ssas, cubes, msbi

I have about 4 attributes in **`Race dimension`** as shown in blow

**dimension name is Race**

1)`Race`
2)`RACE DESC`
3)`RACE KEY`
4)`RACE SHORT NAME`

when go to cube browse and right click on `Race` dimension and select add query 
as  below

1)when i drag Race dimension to browser data panel it showing default Race Attribute data

2)i want show `RACE DESC` data only

3) at the same time i drag the `RACE` DIMENSION in Filter panel

4) i want show `RACE DESC` Attribute only

5) i don't want set **attributehierarchyvisible** =**false**

how do i achieve my above requirement

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own user's hierarchy and place it on the 1st place in dimension hierarchies part of screen. This will let SSAS to use it.

[image: Hierarchies order]

Here `Report Date` hierarchy is selected by default.

And `Product Categories` on the image below:

[image: HierarchiesOrder2]

**UPDATE**

Here is detailed explanation:

Now you have 5 flat hierarchies and server takes first alphabetical one by default, like this (`Count` is measure here):

[image: DraggedDimDefaultHierarchy1]

To fix this, you need to disable attributes hierarchy, which you want to be selected by default:

[image: DraggedDimDefaultHierarchy2]

Than rename attribute, to be able to create user's hierarchy with the same name (so for users this will be identical as previous flat attribute hierarchy):

[image: DraggedDimDefaultHierarchy3]

Finally, process this dimension again, and when you drag dimension, it will show your first user's hierarchy, which is `State` in our case.

[image: DraggedDimDefaultHierarchy4]

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE-2** (New example with races)

To achieve this, you need to do the same as described in UPDATE #1:

1. Rename `RACE DESC` to some other name (e.g. `RACE DESC Attr`) and disable it's hierarchy visibility by setting *attributehierarchyvisible = false*
2. Create user's hierarchy on this attribute with desirable name: `RACE DESC`
3. Process dimension.

That's all. Now default attribute will be `RACE DESC`. It's hierarchy is not disabled, just it's showing priority is changed to be the 1st one.

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex Peshik, could any one can explain more elaborately

Comment: is it not possible with out using hierarchies @Alex Peshik

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your statement. Every attribute used for slicing-dicing has an hierarchy, if it's not manually disabled. Could you please paraphrase or attach an example in you initial question?

Comment: I Have updated my Question With more Details Please look in to it

Comment: Got it. I've updated answer too. Actually, it's the same solution as described in update #1.

Comment: it is good but when i drag to data panel it was showing  attribute name like RACE DESC Attr  i want to show Race Desc , and there is a any chance to get  the above Requirement  using mdx queries means dynamically control the attributes

Comment: No, there is no another way to solve. Do you rename LEVEL name to 'RACE DESC' in user's hierarchy or leave as is (RACE DESC Attr)? It's 3rd image of 1st update, right side with properties. Source is "...Attr", but level name w/o it.